# CQ5 author instance is not Starting

Tags: aem

I am Using 5.6.1 version of Adobe cq5 . I have set Java version 7 as JAVA_HOME . While starting Author instance am getting 500 error.

Comment: Hi Issue is resolved , I started it using CMD prompt

Comment: One issue might be incompatible JAVA version.
Also try to login via `http://host:port/crx/de/index.jsp` directly and recompile the jsp via `http://host:port/system/console/slingjsp`
better clear the already compiled classes/clientlibs under var folder (Example: /var/clientlibs/libs/granite/core/content/login).

Comment: @SandeepKumar screenshots of text are discouraged, and formatted text is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times even if we have java version 7 and AEM 5.6.1 , we face issues while starting the author instance. This can be over come by starting the instance via command prompt.